# accessing nested json properties dynamically in logic app

Tags: json, nested, syntax-error, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to acces a nested property inside a json body dynamically.
I have a json from an http get request to sharepoint.
The body that looks like this:

```
{
    "odata.nextLink": "somelink",
    "value": [{
            "ColumnName": {
                "Id": "int_id",
                "Title": "sometitle"
            }
        },
        {
            "ColumnName": {
                "Id": "int_id2",
                "Title": "sometitle2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The column name is determined dynamically from a pipeline and a config table and i get using a post request
This is the structure that the post request is receiving:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "ColumnName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

I have built an until loop that loops over all the bodies inside the value property with an iterator i that starts at 0 and increments until i equals the number of bodies inside the value property minus 1.

I need to extract only the id and title so i have introduced a parse json inside the for loop in which i wanted to get the body as follows:

```
body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['value']?[variables('i')]?['variables('ColumName')']
```

If i hardcode the columnname i get no errors and the logic app works fine, however as soon as i change it to get the columnname out of the variable i get a syntax error and i cant quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure I fully understand AND this is untested but there is an obvious error with your syntax.

Change this ...

```
body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['value']?[variables('i')]?['variables('ColumName')']
```

... to this ...

```
body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['value']?[variables('i')]?[variables('ColumName')]
```

... i.e. remove those single quotes in the last part of the expression.